# Logging TWindowsVersion in Inno Setup

Tags: inno-setup, pascalscript

Previously I was using:

```pascal
{ Check Windows Version }
WindowsVersion := GetWindowsVersion;
Log(Format('Windows Version: %x', [WindowsVersion]));
```

Now I am using:

```pascal
{ Check Windows Version }
GetWindowsVersionEx(WinVer);
WinVerPacked := PackVersionComponents(WinVer.Major, WinVer.Minor, WinVer.Build, 0);
```

Where `WinVer` is of type `TWindowsVersion`. How do we now handle the `Log` entry?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Why do you want to log it, if it is logged already by Inno Setup?

  ```
  2020-11-17 16:26:59.234   Windows version: 10.0.19041  (NT platform: Yes)
  ```
- Anyway, there's nothing preventing you from continuing to use `GetWindowsVersion` for logging purposes, even if you now use `GetWindowsVersionEx` for the version check.
- [`PackVersionComponents`](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=isxfunc_packversioncomponents) return value is actually similar to `GetWindowsVersion`, so you can log it directly:

  ```pascal
  Log(Format('Windows Version: %x', [WinVerPacked]));
  ```

  It will just have more zeroes in the output:

  ```
  2020-11-17 16:26:59.337   Windows Version: A00004A610000
  ```

  Though it's similarly user unfriendly as your previous logging of `GetWindowsVersion`:

  ```
  2020-11-17 16:26:59.337   Windows Version: A004A61
  ```
- More user friendly is indeed to use [`TWindowsVersion`](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=isxfunc_getwindowsversionex) components.

  ```pascal
  Log(Format('Windows Version: %d.%d.%d', [WinVer.Major, WinVer.Minor, WinVer.Build]));
  ```

  That will get you what Inno Setup logs in its header:

  ```
  2020-11-17 16:26:59.337   Windows Version: 10.0.19041
  ```
- Though, if you log `TWindowsVersion` returned by `GetWindowsVersionEx`, you can make your life easier by logging output of [`GetWindowsVersionString`](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=isxfunc_getwindowsversionstring):

  ```pascal
  Log(Format('Windows Version: %s', [GetWindowsVersionString]));
  ```

  which does pretty much the same:

  ```
  2020-11-17 16:26:59.337   Windows Version: 10.00.19041
  ```